# Inappropriate behaviour of ImapMailReceiver

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, imap

If the password contains @, ImapMailReceiver failed to return host correctly.

for example:

> username: abc@gmail.com
>
> password: abc@123
>
> host: imap.gmail.com

**Final URI string**

> imap://abc@gmail.com:abc@123@imap.gmail.com:993/INBOX

then, ImapMailReceiver identify host as 123@imap.gmail.com

I checked [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/125850-bug-found-in-imapmailreceiver) thread but I use JavaConfig way to create ImapMailReceiver where as the thread is about XML config way.

Any way to walk around of this issue?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

**Final URI string with encoding**

> imap://abc%40gmail.com:abc%40123@imap.gmail.com:993/INBOX

in this case, I got AuthenticationException.

May be above information help you to understand the problem.

**UPDATE 1**

above was an issue from Gmail. One need to enable LESS SECURE APP security option in Gmail to fix Authentication related issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) says:

```
Within the user and password field, any ":", "@", or "/" must be encoded.
```

I expect you already know how URL encoding works. If you want a refresher, page 18 of the same document is a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I know URL encoding. I even tried encoding password but that time I got AuthenticationException.

Comment: GMail doesn't allow the javamail client by default; you have to go into the account settings and reduce the security requirements; don't ask me how, I'd have to google it again myself.

Comment: @GaryRussell thanks for pointing out security issue. I forgot to enable LESS SECURE APP security setting in Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem with an Office 365 account, where the user name is like 'your-user@your-company.com' and the host is 'outlook.office365.com'. Without encoding the user name, 'your-company.com' is used as the host, which leads to the following (a bit misleading) error:

> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect, no password specified?

Activating debugging with mail.debug=true ...

```
mailProps.put("mail.debug", "true");
receiver.setJavaMailProperties(mailProps);
```

... gives us the parameters used for the connection to the mail server.

> DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect returning false, host = your-company.com, user = your-user, password = <null>

To resolve the issue, I used URLEncoder.encode for the username and password, e.g.:

```
...
new StringBuilder("imaps://")
   .append(URLEncoder.encode(mailSettings.getUser(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()))
   .append(":")
   .append(URLEncoder.encode(mailSettings.getPassword(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()))
...
```